# How do I put a method as a parameter in a method call?

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to write a method in java that passes in another method as a parameter.

This is the method call in main:

```
    Functions.print("total",Functions.compute(scoreArray),Functions.find(scoreArray));
```

So far i have this as the method signature:

```
    public void print(String str, ...)
```

I have the compute and find methods already written. I don't know how to input them as parameters.

Comment: What do you think `javascript` and `java` are?

Comment: Perhaps you could use an interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can't currently do it with Java (well, you can but it's really roundabout)

There's a guava library that makes it easier to do functional programming with collections:  https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not directly. Create an interface:

```
public interface MyFuncFromAToB{
    public SomeClass calculate(SomeOtherClass in);
}
```

and accept that.

<sub>On Java 8 you'll be able to use Lambdas. When that comes around keep accepting the same interface(it must have only *one* method) and you'll receive lambdas and method pointers with that signature.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Java and javascript are two very different languages. Java (currently) doesn't have any functional programming features; methods (functions) are not Objects and so cannot be passed around like objects.